# Scanner through a line with whitespace and comma

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java and looking for some help with Java's Scanner class. Below is the problem.
I have a text file with multiple lines and each line having multiple pairs of digit.Such that each pair of digit is represented as ( digit,digit ). For example 3,3 6,4 7,9.  All these multiple pairs of digits are seperated from each other by a whitespace. Below is an exampel from the text file.

1 2,3 3,2 4,5

2 1,3 4,2 6,13

3 1,2 4,2 5,5

What i want is that i can retrieve each digit seperately. So that i can create an array of linkedlist out it. Below is what i have acheived so far.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("a.txt"));
    Scanner lineSc;
    String line;
    Integer vertix = 0;
    Integer length = 0;
    sc.useDelimiter("\\n"); // For line feeds

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        lineSc = new Scanner(line);

        lineSc.useDelimiter("\\s"); // For Whitespace
        // What should i do here. How should i scan through considering the whitespace and comma
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a regular expression, and data that doesn't conform to your expectation will be easily identified and dealt with.

```
CharSequence inputStr = "2 1,3 4,2 6,13";    
String patternStr = "(\\d)\\s+(\\d),";    
// Compile and use regular expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);

while (matcher.find()) {
    // Get all groups for this match
    for (int i=0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        String groupStr = matcher.group(i);
    }
}
```

Group one and group two will correspond to the first and second digit in each pairing, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. But the above solution gives me output in the form 2 1 then 3 4 then 2 6 and ignoring 13. What i want is that i should have the first digit 2. Then there are the pairs of digit 1,3 then 4,2 and then 6,13. Also i want to have it in form of seperate integers and not as a group. because i want to transform the lines to an array such that Array[2][0] = {1,3} , Array[2][1] = {4,2} and soo on ..

Answer (score 0):

**1.** use `nextLine()` method of Scanner to get the **each Entire line of text** from the File.

**2.** Then use `BreakIterator` class with its static method `getCharacterInstance()`, to get the individual character, **it will automatically handle commas, spaces, etc.**

**3.** `BreakIterator` also give you many flexible methods to separate out the sentences, words etc.

For more details see this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the StringTokenizer class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

```
//this is in the while loop
//read each line
String line=sc.nextLine();

//create StringTokenizer, parsing with space and comma
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line," ,");
```

Then each digit is read as a string when you call nextToken() like this, if you wanted all digits in the line

```
while(st1.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String temp=st1.nextToken();

    //now if you want it as an integer
    int digit=Integer.parseInt(temp);

    //now you have the digit! insert it into the linkedlist or wherever you want
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use split(regex), more simple :

```
 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      final String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" |,");
      // What should i do here. How should i scan through considering the whitespace and comma
      for(int num : line) { 
            // Do your job
      }        
 }
```